# Activity not found while using a service

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, sensors

I am trying to start a Service that implements SensorEventListener.  I am getting an error in my logcat claiming:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.devicemoved/com.devicemoved.ShakeWakeupService}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

My Service is declared in my manifest as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devicemoved"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.devicemoved.launcherGo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.devicemoved.ShakeWakeupService" />
</application>
```

The Activity

```
public class ShakeWakeupService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private Context mContext;

    SensorManager mSensorEventManager;

    Sensor mSensor;
    // BroadcastReceiver for handling ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.
    public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Check action just to be on the safe side.
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                Log.v("shake mediator screen off", "trying re-registration");
                // Unregisters the listener and registers it again.
                mSensorEventManager.unregisterListener(ShakeWakeupService.this);
                mSensorEventManager.registerListener(ShakeWakeupService.this,
                        mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v("shake service startup", "registering for shake");

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        // Obtain a reference to system-wide sensor event manager.
        mSensorEventManager = (SensorManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Get the default sensor for accel
        mSensor = mSensorEventManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        // Register for events.
        mSensorEventManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Register our receiver for the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF action. This will
        // make our receiver
        // code be called whenever the phone enters standby mode.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Unregister our receiver.
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

        // Unregister from SensorManager.
        mSensorEventManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't need a IBinder interface.
        return null;
    }

    public void onShake() {
        // Poke a user activity to cause wake?

    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // not used right now
    }

    // Used to decide if it is a shake
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            return;

        Log.v("sensor", "sensor change is verifying");

    }
}
```

The only thing I could possibly think of is that I am suppose to declare a broadcast receiver since I am using it in my class but I am not sure how to do that in this instance because I am not extending Broadcastreceiver.

I am calling this class from an activity with a button.

Any help will be great Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already declared the package in the manifest tag, you should only need the .ShakeWakeupService part. Also make sure there is an empty constructor available for the system to construct your service

Comment: That was good advice, it is true my package already declares com.devicemoved, i seem to redeclare it out of habit.  My porogram no longer force closes i was launching startActivity(intent); instead of startService(intent), my program no longer Fcloses but it doesnt seem like my serviceclass is running, please explain what is meant by service  needs empty constructor

Comment: @Program or die If you are extending IntentService class then you need empty constructor.Since you are extending service no need of empty constructor.